# Why Angular ngStyle directive doesn't work?

Tags: css, angular

I want to change one css property according to the condition but my code doesn't work.

```
      <form
    #deviceTypeForm
    id="device-types-form"
    class="column column--with-gap"
    [ngStyle]="{ 'grid-template-columns': this.router.url.includes('new') ? '60px 1fr 60px' : '1fr 1fr' }"
  >
```

earlier it was in css file :

```
    :host {
  display: grid;
  padding: variables.$spacing;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 1fr 60px;
  gap: variables.$spacing;
}
```

but now I want to make conditioning changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You applied the style to the `:host` selector, now you put it on the `form` selector.

A `form` has no `display` property, so id you try to add grid layout to the form, you first have to add a `display: grid` to it.

Also, the `this.router` can just be `router`.